# How to set thread name in dpdk 18.11

Tags: dpdk

in dpdk 17.05 struct lcore_config is public and pthread_t can get by lcore_config[lcore_id].thread_id
in 18.11 struct lcore_config is private, how can I get pthread_t for lcore_id?

Problem - I can't set thread name with pthread_setname_np(<pthread_here>, "my_thread_name");

`rte_gettid()` returns `int` but I need `pthread_t`

Comment: Is your question does rte_gettid returns the pid or not? because this conflicts with the explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in DPDK `rte_lcore.h` the API `rte_thread_setname` is responsible for setting alternate name rather than DPDK assigned name. In Linux DPDK internally invokes `pthread_setname_np`.

DPDK version: dpdk-stable-18.11.10
[edit-1] as per the DPDK code base setname if you have glbc > 2.12
glibc version: Ubuntu GLIBC 2.30-0ubuntu2.2

Code modified in C file:

```
        printf("hello from core %u\n", lcore_id);
        snprintf(name, 100, "hello-%d", lcore_id);
                if (rte_thread_setname( pthread_self(), name) == 0)
                                printf(" thread name %s\n", name);
```

CFLAGS added to Makefile:

```
CFLAGS += -DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API
```

or build using `EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API make`

```
36986 root      20   0  227916   6996   6024 R 93.8  0.0   0:40.60 helloworld
37004 root      20   0  227916   6996   6024 R 93.8  0.0   0:40.61 lcore-slave-1
37005 root      20   0  227916   6996   6024 R 93.8  0.0   0:40.61 lcore-slave-2
37006 root      20   0  227916   6996   6024 R 93.8  0.0   0:40.61 lcore-slave-3
```

After invoking

```
15326 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:03.32 hello-0
15327 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:00.00 eal-intr-thread
15328 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:00.00 rte_mp_handle
15329 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:03.32 hello-1
15330 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:03.32 hello-2
15331 root      20   0  153312   7728   5976 T   0.0   0.2   0:03.32 hello-3
```